# FreeRADIUS EAP password

Tags: passwords, radius, freeradius

At our company, we are using RADIUS to authenticate users in our VPN and internal network.

We use Google Apps at the company, so we developed a module (we didn't find any that do it already) that validates the user account with Google.

Because of that, we need to retrieve the user and password from the RADIUS packet in order to validate it with Google.

I will be trying to get the password from the packet, but I can't get it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on which EAP method you are using. Most use challenge-response, so it's impossible to get a plain text password (e.g. `EAP-TLS`, `PEAP/EAP-MSCHAPv2`, or `EAP-TTLS/MSCHAPv2`).

You are able to get a plaintext password with a few, the most common is probably `EAP-TTLS/PAP`, but historically has been supported in less supplicants than, say, the MSCHAP methods, though this is improving.

If you're not using EAP then again, it depends on what is being used. `PAP` will send a plain User-Password attribute; `CHAP` or `MS-CHAP` are challenge-response, so you can't get the plain password.